# How do I add Postgres.app to PATH variable?

Tags: macos, postgresql, unix, terminal

I'm trying to install Postgres.app on my Mac. I've got it downloaded but in the docs on their website it says:

> PostgreSQL ships with a constellation of useful binaries, like pg_dump or pg_restore, that you will likely want to use. Go ahead and add the /bin directory that ships with Postgres.app to your PATH (preferably in .profile, .bashrc, .zshrc, or the like to make sure this gets set for every Terminal session):
>
> PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"

Where would I enter that? And what would my `PATH` be?

Also heres the website's [docs](http://postgresapp.com/documentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$PATH` variable into a `UNIX` (so even OSX) is a environment variable of the system that tells to the system itself where to search for binary files (executables)

You should run a terminal and paste that string

```
PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"
```

You're telling to your system to give to PATH variable a new value formed by `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin` (that will contain your postgress binaries) and the previous value of `$PATH` (used to avoid overriding)

To launch a terminal on OSX you should act like follow:

- Navigate to `Application/Utilities`
- Double click on terminal Icon

#### N.B.:

This method is valid only for "a session"; when you turn off your pc, `$PATH` variable will be restored to "default value". If you want to make that change persistent [only for your current user] follow this (from terminal)

```
echo 'export PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: Alright. I did that, now this is what happens http://postimg.org/image/i4va6h3it/

Comment: @user3285218: ok now if you write `echo $PATH` you should notice that even the postgres binary will be included. Now you can use it from the command line, like follows: `psql -h localhost` (command line = terminal command). If you want to use the GUI, you should procede like avery other program that you install into MacOSX

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, so far. So after I do `echo $PATH` I see the location. Then when I attempt to do `psql -h localhost`, It tells me the command was not found. http://postimg.org/image/e39nafb2j/ @DonCallisto

Comment: @user3285218: could you paste the output of `ls -la /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin` ?

Comment: I found out that the app name was `Postgres93.app` So I changed it to `Postgres.app`. I got things working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$PATH is an environment variable used on all Unix machines (and Windows apparently). Try this: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appleosx-bash-unix-change-set-path-environment-variable/

Comment: So it would turn into `PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH/.profile"`?